# OpenVPN setup issues

Tags: web-server, server

I have been following the guide here: http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/technology-33548728 To set up an openvpn server on my pi.

I have followed all the steps but when it comes to connecting, it is not working.
From my vpn client I get the following error:

```
Connecting to [correct Ip Address]:1194 via UDPv4
EVENT: CONNECTION_TIMEOUT
```

I set up port forwarding on my router for UDP 1194, and looking at the logs for that I can see that it is allowing the traffic through.

I then looked at the openvpn log on my pi, but it is not updating when a connection attempt is made.

So I need to work out how to see what happens to the traffic when it is forwarded to the pi. Is there some sort of log I can look at to see what is happening after my router forwards the traffic to my pi?

nmap returns that the port is open

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Following [this guide](https://www.raspberrypi.org/forums/viewtopic.php?t=81657) I added the following lines to my `/etc/rc.local` file that sets up all the iptables configurations and starts the server at every boot. This worked for me on Raspbian Wheezy and now Jessie.

```
iptables -A INPUT -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A OUTPUT -o tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -s 10.8.0.0/24 -o eth0 -j MASQUERADE
iptables -I FORWARD -i tun0 -o eth0 -s 10.8.0.0/24 -d 192.168.0.0/24 -m conntrack --ctstate NEW -j ACCEPT
iptables -A INPUT -i eth0 -m state --state NEW -p udp --dport 1194 -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i tun+ -o eth0 -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
iptables -A FORWARD -i eth0 -o tun+ -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
service openvpn restart
```

Answer (score 0):

Try doing it over TCP. Your ISP may be blocking UDP traffic or they're reserving it for themselves (e.g. IPTV, etc.)

Source: Experience